# ffmpeg record with minimal CPU usage or hardware acceleration

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, performance, gpu

How to record video with ffmpeg in hd with minimal CPU usage or use hardware acceleration with an integrated intel gpu?

Currently I have at least 20% of cpu used (using -preset faster), I would like to record with at most 10% of cpu used (60 fps and hd). Here is my configuration:

gpu: HD Graphics 630
proc: 64-bitProcessors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-7500T CPU @ 2.70GHz

I have try with hardware acceleration:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -i :0 -c:v h264_vaapi output.mp4
```

only I have this error

```
    Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I would like to have an answer that tells me either: a way to run ffmpeg with a minimum cpu usage of 10% or to help me run hardware acceleration (and please don't tell me to use obs, I need ffmpeg to code a project).

Comment: There are a lot of VAAPI command line examples at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI

Comment: Alternatively apparently on Linux there is also `libmfx` that supports harware encoding using QuickSync: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync

Comment: @Mokubai On this website, I have `Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at trac.ffmpeg.org Port 80`

Comment: Please try reloading, the site seems somewhat odd at the moment but those pages do have a lot of good info. I suspect the site went down briefly and some caching CDN is having trouble, but it *is* there.

Comment: Alternatively, wayback links: [VAAPI](https://web.archive.org/web/20211109170135/https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/VAAPI) and [QuickSync](https://web.archive.org/web/20211109170246/https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync)

Comment: okay, but the problem is that I don't have the qsv decoder `ffmpeg -encoders|grep qsv` so I can't use these examples^^

Comment: Can you recompile or get a version that *does* have qsv? If there are limitations on your system or version of `ffmpeg` then that would be good information to have in your question.

Comment: My version of ffmpeg: `ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1`I will try to see how to have the latest version, but is it possible to make a version that can be sent to users, I want to make a program and compile ffmpeg for each user would be very long (well I think)

Comment: I compiled the latest version of ffmpeg but I still have this problem.
`./ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_qsv
ffmpeg version N-104546-g2ece70090d Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      57.  8.100 / 57.  8.100
  libavcodec     59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavformat    59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 16.101 /  8. 16.101
  libswscale      6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
Codec 'h264_qsv' is not recognized by FFmpeg.
`